# Как отключить автоматический переход в режим игры при запуске ее в Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как отключить автоматический переход в режим игры при запуске ее в Unity? При нажатии кнопки "Play", unity автоматически перекидывает меня в режим игры, однако мне хочется остаться в режиме редактирования объектов (сцена). Возможно я где-то упустил отключение этой функции в настройках. Заранее спасибо

Comment: В рантайме перейдите из окна Game в окно Scene

Comment: @АлександрДаниловский Надо чтобы сразу после начала я был в сцене

Comment: так перетащите окна Юнити, чтобы одновременно и то, и другое отображалось.

Comment: Вы можете перемещать любые окна Unity куда угодно, нажав на его заголовок ЛКМ и потащив. Вы можете сделать так, чтобы было одновременно видно и Play и Scene. Однако по умолчанию при запуске игры Unity открывает окно Play если оно свернуто

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В окне "Game" нажать на "Play Focused" и в выпавшем меню выбрать "Play Unfocused"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Выберите пункт в настройках, который показан на изображении ниже (или выше). Он сделает вам два окна слева (одно слева-сверху - это режим редактирования. Второе слева-снизу - это режим игры). Можете там выбрать любой другой пункт, который Вам понравится, а можете сделать свой: Вы можете добавлять любое окно и любое их количество, а также перетаскивать их как угодно.